# Cognos 10 Report Studio List - Totaling Dynamic Columns

Tags: grouping, cognos-10

I am writing a list in Cognos Report Studio 10.2 and am fairly new with it.  The list has are over 10 columns where the user can select which columns they want to display in the report.  That is currently working fine with render variables and static choices.  I now need to add a column that will give a count of the number of ID’s per group.  I created a data item and used `count(distinct[ID])` and it is producing the correct totals, but it is grouping by all the columns not just on the columns that are being displayed. How do I group the columns that are being displayed correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by *it is grouping by all the columns*? Which columns did you explicitly pick for grouping?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I am new to posting on this site and thought I set it up to email me.

Comment: Column 1 and 2 are not included in the users choice of columns and only contain one value. If I run the report with just those two columns, I get one row with the correct total.
Column 3 and 4 are columns the user can choose to show or not.  Column 3 has 8 values and column 4 has 17.  If I run the report and chose both columns, the report totals correctly.  If I chose column 3, the report has 17 rows instead of 8 rows.   If I run with column 4, it has 17 rows.

Comment: So, the assumption is that you have grouping activated for column 3 and 4 but you show either 3 or 4 or (3 and 4). Which column does the `[ID]` in `count(distinct[ID])` relate to?

Comment: One thought: suppose `[ID]` does not relate to the values in either column 3 or 4 try the following: introduce another data item called `GroupingValue` which is computed by concatenating the values from the **active** columns using `CASE WHEN END` constructs. You may have to cast to strings if the values are numeric to be able to concatenate. Then, replace `count(distinct[ID])` by `count(distinct[GroupingValue])`, remove the grouping on all columns except for the `GroupingValue` and see what happens.

Comment: I don't have grouping on any of the columns, but I tried adding it to various combinations of columns.  The [ID] is the customer_id and one of the primary keys.  I thought it would be the best way to count the number of times the customer's row met the filter criteria.  Thank you for the suggestion and for making it easy for a beginner to follow.  I will try it out now.